# Sort the array according to the alphabetic order of the last names of the students

Tags: c, arrays, loops, sorting

*Sort the array according to the alphabetic order of the last names of the students and print the array to the console.*

**But the code does not show the output correctly, why?**

*If i give input. Suppose,*

**input:**

```
Enter the value of number: 2
Please enter the name of the student:
Nihan ahmed
```

**output:**

```
After sorting the array:
Nihan ahmed
```

**Why can't I input more than one name?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{   
    char name[10][8], temp[8];
    int i,j,n,L,k;
    printf("Enter the value of number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Please enter the name of the student:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        gets(name[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        while(1)
        {
            ++k;
            if(name[i][k]==' ')
            break;
        }
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
           L=0;
           while(1)
           {
               ++L;
               if(name[j][L]==' ')
               break;
           }
            if(name[i][k+1]>name[j][L+1])
            {
               strcpy(temp,name[i]);
               strcpy(name[i],name[j]);
               strcpy(name[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("After sorting the array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        puts(name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are reading n times according to this loop :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   gets(name[i]);
}
```

what this loop is doing is reading a 10 words, when you write nihan ahmed you are storing 2 string name[0] has Nisan in it and name[1] has Ahmed in it

what you need to do (if you are not familiar with structures which seems like) is:

```
for(i=0;i<2*n;i++)
{
   printf ("\n please enter the name of the student number %d: ", i);
   gets(name[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here : `gets(name[i]);` is have some limitation related to get input from user. 
I advice to use `scanf(" %s", name[i])` .
In your code if you put print in

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d \n", i);
    gets(name[i]);
}

OUTPUT:
Enter the value of number:
2

Please enter the name of the student:
0 
1 
hello
After sorting the array:

hello
```

You will find that 0, 1 print will come at a time in stand of 0 -> (wait for input) -> 1 -> (wait for input).

if you use scanf in stand of gets code work as expected. 
please change the code of gets loop with :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",name[i]);
}

OUTPUT:
Enter the value of number:
2

Please enter the name of the student:
hello 
abcd
After sorting the array:
hello
abcd
```